# Is this slightly exposed wire dangerous?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I accidentally cut through the insulation on this cable earlier with a small metal saw and noticed that part of the wire is now exposed. I don't know what the wire is actually for; it runs inside a cupboard and up towards the ceiling and out into the direction of my en suite bathroom, then disappears.

[image]

Is this potentially dangerous or would covering it with electrical tape be fine? As I didn't get an electric shock when I cut through it, I'm guessing that the bit showing isn't part of the live wire? Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  *Weird. Why is the copper conductor **so very wide?*** Search the cable for any markings, we really, really need them!

Comment: This might be coax for TV or something other than regular mains cabling.

Comment: Single wire cable not in conduit, looks like coax or similar as manassehkatz has pointed out. Figuring out what this is would tell more, look for numbers like rg6 , rg58 ,rg59 , these are all types of communications cable if so a simple wrap of tape would be fine if another type of cable or additional wires not pictured it could be hazardous but there is not enough information to make an informed call.